# A single word for hardware and peripherals

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that combines hardware and peripherals into one. Laptops, mouses, printers, projectors, (loud)speakers, headphones, power cords, chargers, extension cords... all of this I need to fit into a single word and neither hardware nor peripherals nor devices cuts it.

The word has to be concise yet descriptive, so that whenever anyone reads it, he/she will immidiately (without thinking) know what's behind this word. It also has to be appropriate enough so that the reader doesn't start questioning the name, e.g. "Why someone put printer ink cartridge in hardware category?".
The word itself will be used as a class name in a coding project, but I do not believe this information impacts the question in any additional way, as the rules for class naming basically boil down to: short, preferably one-wordish (since no spaces or such are allowed) and as descriptive as possible.

Comment: What's wrong with hardware, out of interest?

Comment: Cords and chargers for example are hardly perceived as hardware, so using 'hardware' wouldn't give the whole picture to the readers. I'm also not sure if e.g. ink cartridges for printers are considered hardware. On the other hand, mouse is more often referred to as a peripheral rather than hardware, so once again, readers wouldn't get the full picture.

Comment: meh.  I'd stick with "computer hardware and peripherals" then.  Sorry that's not very helpful but it might save you some time in the long run.

Comment: Naming a class and then a table in database with such a long name is a no-go, sadly.

Comment: **paraphernalia**?  Not only the central components but all the odds and ends that go with a particular hobby or profession--whether computing, photography, mountain climbing, the practice of medicine.

Comment: Seems to be the only option so far, though I don't like how it strays away from the computing area.

Comment: I'd suggest "assets" but it's too broad. even if you narrowed it to "ICT assets" that would still include software, licenses and the like. +1 for a tough question.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - that's not the worst suggestion since it comes with a solid acronym - CHAPs (or CHaPs, if you don't mind the retro throwback)

Comment: Perhaps **electricals**?

Comment: This is just for a database table?  Who cares, call it what you want.

Comment: As far as database table naming goes i'd call it "hardware_items".

Comment: @MaxWilliams it's for a class name for the EntityFramework Code First approach, so it might be later made into a table name too (unless I specify a rule to name it differently, but I'd prefer not splitting class and table, since it goes somewhat against CF approach).

Comment: I'd just say "hardware".  But then I've only been computing since 1968.

Comment: @Vocoder I like the idea of an acronym, although I'm not sure if it's acceptable as a class name in a programming project.

Comment: Is this the best stack for this question? Since it seems to require understanding of naming conventions for databases and all whatnot, might it find more sector specific responses somewhere like https://superuser.com ? I understand that its asking for an english word, but it seems to be hedged about with rules which aren't related to standard English usage. At the very least a jargon/terminology tag would give a heads-up that it isn't as simple a question as first appears and get more tailored replies..

Comment: What's your **system**?

Comment: All the items you mentioned are hardware: peripherals are a subset of hardware, and computers are another subset of hardware. Call the dang table 'hardware', already! Shucks. ;)

Comment: @ArchContrarian after sleeping on it, I'm slowly coming to terms with this option, as it seems there are hardly any better names. Do you have anything to back up that "subset" statement though?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming variables etc. are specifically [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). These sorts of questions tend to result in plenty of answers which are acceptable from a *language* point of view, which the OP then rejects for non-language reasons. This is a *language* SE.

Comment: Equipment . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the word *electronics*? ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/electronics))

> electronic components, devices, or equipment

Comment: @SteveLovell propsed "electricals", which is very similiar to this, but I'd guess people would be somewhat confused if they saw a printer ink cartridge being classified as any of that. Aside from that, I like these propositions.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 4):

***Kit***

Whilst the word isn't particular to computing, it is certainly a term that would be understood in my sort of general office environment, in the UK, as 'encompassing all the bits you need'.
The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/103713?rskey=oyYBof&result=1#eid) (login required0 defines it thus:

> 3. *colloq*. A number of things or persons viewed as a whole; a set, lot, collection; esp. in phr. ***the whole kit***

The [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kit) has this definition:

> A set of articles or equipment needed for a specific purpose.

Comment: I believe it's _too_ broad. Class naming standards say that the name should be concise enough for the reader to understand what it represents at a first glance, and "kit" fails to do that.

Comment: Okay, but it seems as though you are looking for something which fits a set of rules which are separate from English language usage. per se, and perhaps not known to everyone. If those 'Class naming standards' and 'EntityFramework Code First' requirements, whatever their origin, are crucial, then you might get more tailored answers if you are explicit about those rules and their source *in the question*. That would also be helpful for people in the future looking for answers with the same limitations. As the Q stands there is nothing about these specifics.

Comment: @user6807975 — What are class naming standards and if they are relevant why are they not mentioned in the question? Kit is what occurred to me as a single word, but better with an adjective "computer kit". If you are looking for an, e.g. Java, variable name, computerKit.

Comment: Programming naming standards are in no way to be treated in an off-wordly manner. If we generalize a bit, the rules basically boil down to 'your code has to be concise and as readable as a book would be', so if your reader looks at a name and has to wonder what it means or what it even is, then your code most likely needs more attention, that's why I believe it's not different from a situation an English speaker might end up in. I'm looking for a single word that concisely describes a group of 'IT' objects and that's what question already contains. Very well though, I'll expand it.

Comment: @user6807975 The reason that the 'single-word request' tag requirements include '*please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE*' is that in English writing, words are generally understood within a context. A word's meaning can be instantly understood within a larger piece when it may be ambiguous in isolation. That's why words can have multiple meanings, you know which is appropriate *from context*. If **your** word must be unambiguous, *absent* context, that is exceptional enough to merit specifying. Which I see you have done, kinda.

Answer (score 0):

**Accessory** /noun

1.
a subordinate or supplementary part, object, or the like, used mainly for convenience, attractiveness, safety, etc., as a spotlight on an automobile or a lens cover on a camera.

I would use this word for anything that works alongside a "main device." Unfortunately I'm not sure I would use it for the laptop, unless the laptop is supporting something else.